# a = open("file", "r"); a.readline() output without \n

Tags: python

I am about to write a python script, that is able to read a txt file, but with readline() there is always the \n output. How can i remove this from the variable ?

```
a = open("file", "r")
b = a.readline()
a.close()
```

Comment: Remove the last element of the string...

Comment: this isn't a duplicate. OP is looking for reading a line out of a file without a newline. While the solution for them may be to rstrip(), the file-specific operations are worth exploring.

Answer (score 51):

That would be:

```
b.rstrip('\n')
```

If you want to strip space from each and every line, you might consider instead:

```
a.read().splitlines()
```

This will give you a list of lines, without the line end characters.

Answer (score 30):

A solution, can be:

```
with open("file", "r") as fd:
    lines = fd.read().splitlines()
```

You get the list of lines without "\r\n" or "\n".

Or, use the classic way:

```
with open("file", "r") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.strip()
```

You read the file, line by line and drop the spaces and newlines.

If you only want to drop the newlines:

```
with open("file", "r") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
```

Et voilà.

**Note:** The behavior of Python 3 is a little different. To mimic this behavior, use `io.open`.

See the documentation of [io.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html?highlight=io.open#io.open).

So, you can use:

```
with io.open("file", "r", newline=None) as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
```

When the *newline* parameter is `None`: lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n'.

> *newline* controls how universal newlines works (it only applies to text mode). It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'. It works as follows:
>
> On input, if newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller. If it is '', universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.

Comment: Too bad the topic was closed as duplicate. This is the best answer between this topis and the other one considered the non-duplicate post.