# While loop is not breaking python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time

I am currently trying to compare the current date and time to a date and time which are written down in another file. For some weird reason the while loop is not breaking but creating an endless loop.

This is what the `test.txt` file I try to compare the current date and time with contains:
`29.10.2021 20:47:47`

This is my code
(Imagine `ga` is equal to the data in the `test.txt` ):

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def background_checker():
    with open('test.txt','r+') as sample:
        while True:
            ga = datetime.now()
            ga = ga.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
            print(ga, end='\r')
            line = sample.readline()
            if line == ga:#if time and date in file equal to the current time and date, the if statement should be triggered. 
                print('alarm')
                break
background_checker()
```

Am I doing something wrong in my code? If so I would be very glad if someone could explain to me what I've made wrong and how I can solve this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a = open("file", "r"); a.readline() output without \n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921087/a-openfile-r-a-readline-output-without-n) TL;DR when you use `readline()` there's going to be a trailing newline (`'\n'`), so the comparison will always return `False`.

Comment: ``readline()`` includes the trailing newline. It cannot equal a ``strftime`` without a trailing newline.

Comment: There are 2 things I want to say.
1. if the time in your test.txt file is not equal to the time.now() you will never break
2. Consider using the keyword 'in' instead `ga in line` if the line you read in is longer and contains formatting characters

Comment: What are the contents of the file? can you paste them here?

Comment: everytime you run this python file the line `ga = datetime.now()` will assign a different value to the variable `ga`

Comment: @ShabbirHussain the content of the file look like this:`29.10.2021 20:47:47`

Comment: @ShabbirHussain yup until it matches the content of the file. Then it should break

Comment: what is the value of `ga` that is printed?

Comment: @ShabbirHussain the current day, month, year, hour, minute and second.

Comment: What is the exact string?

Comment: @ShabbirHussain there is no exact string because ga is changing every iteration of the while loop

Comment: the thing is that `ga` will always be increasing. What if the time in your file is in the past?

Comment: So just to be clear: The file contains *only* a datetime string like ``29.10.2021 20:47:47`` without a trailing newline? And it represents a datetime that has not passed yet but will happen soon?

Comment: @ShabbirHussain yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create an alarm program but you're comparing strings using string equality. A better approach is to compare datetime objects.

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

def background_checker():
    format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
    with open('test.txt','r+') as sample:
        while True:
            ga = datetime.now()
            print(ga)
            line = sample.readline()
            alarm_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, format)     
            if ga > alarm_time: #if time and date in file equal to the current time and date, the if statement should be triggered. 
                print('alarm')
                break
background_checker()
```